# Trying to COUNT the same table for different values

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `flags` from which I'm trying to extract two `COUNT`s.

I'd like one `COUNT` for the number of flags since the start of the year and a separate `COUNT` for this week's allocation.

The query I'm using is as follows:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(f1.ID) AS `Total Flags`,
  COUNT(f2.ID) AS `Weekly Flags`
FROM `frog_flags`.`flags` f1
LEFT JOIN `frog_flags`.`flags` f2
  ON f1.`ID` = f2.`ID`
WHERE
  f2.`Datetime` > '2013-07-08 00:00:00'
AND 
  ( f1.`Staff_ID` = '12345' AND f2.`Staff_ID` = '12345')
AND
  f1.`Datetime` > '2012-09-01 00:00:00'
```

Even though I have data in place, it's showing `0` for both the `Total Flags` and the `Weekly Flags`.

I suspect I've confused my `WHERE` clauses for trying to JOIN the same table twice.

Am I using my clauses incorrectly when trying to COUNT the same table for different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cross-tab SQL query - it's a great design pattern once you get the hang of it:

```
SELECT
  sum( case when `Datetime`> '2012-09-01 00:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) AS `Total Flags`,
  sum( case when `Datetime`> '2013-07-08 00:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) AS `Weekly Flags`
FROM `frog_flags`.`flags` f1
WHERE  f1.`Staff_ID` = '12345'
```

You use a condition to create basically boolean flags which get summed up - this allows for a number of predefined new columns instead of rows.

You could take it further and do it for all staff simultaneously:

```
SELECT
f1.`Staff_ID`,

  sum( case when `Datetime`> '2012-09-01 00:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) AS `Total Flags`,
  sum( case when `Datetime`> '2013-07-08 00:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) AS `Weekly Flags`
FROM `frog_flags`.`flags` f1
WHERE  f1.`Staff_ID` = '12345'
GROUP BY f1.`Staff_ID`
```

Comment: Beautiful way of doing it, indeed. Cheers :)